# search/filter a specific css property on all elements with Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I've been looking for a css property for a long time it's really annoying to go through all elements one by one to disable/enable a property so is it possible to search or filter for a specific css property on all elements?

Comment: You can enter XPath or CSS selectors in Ctrl-F input.

Comment: Thank you that's what i've been looking for !

Comment: you can also just go to the "computed" tab on the right and it gives you every css property declared for the whole document. Click on a specific property to see which elements it applies to